# Python, Tkinter - UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Label' referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have just started to learn python & tkinter and during developing simple program, I'm receiving `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Label' referenced before assignment`, while pressing `Team` Button. `Individual` button works as planned.

I don't understand how to solve this problem.
My code:

```
Label = Label(root, text = "How many members in your team")
Label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2,padx = 20,pady = 20)
```

Comment: In the line `Label = Label(root, text = "Entering as team or individual")` what is the `Label` on the RHS of `=` sign?

Comment: change `Label = Label(...)` to `my_label = Label(...)`

Comment: @RitwikG its the tkinter `Label` class imported on the line: `from tkinter import *`

Comment: Okay. I think the error could be since he is changing the `Label` variable as return value of `Label(root, text = "Entering as team or individual")`. @TheLizzard as you suggested making change should resolve the issue. @Student anyway try to add the error trace as it will clarify where exactly this error is thrown.

Comment: Your code is way too unpythonic (I tried and failed fixing it). You keep referencing `Label` (as a `tkinter.Label` object) before defining it. You have widgets overlapping. You have imports scattered around your program. You don't even use consistent white spacing. Your variable names aren't helpful at all. Why do you have `global Tk`?

Comment: The error occurs when I ask the user the next question which is Label = Label(root, text = "How many members in your team") but I’ll try your solutions and I’ll keep you guys updated thanks!

Comment: Ok, the code you guys provided me is not working still, the same error message appears :(

Comment: @Student edit the question with the updated code

Comment: ok it is edited

Answer (score 1):

When you do `Label = Label(...)`, python sees the `Label =` part and deduces that `Label` is a local variable since you didn't declare it global. Then, when python tries to do `Label(...)`, it still thinks `Label` is a local variable, but it hasn't been initialized yet so it throws `local variable 'Label' referenced before assignment` error.

The root of the problem is that you're using `Label` for a variable name, but `Label` has already been imported as a class name.

The fix is simple: don't create a variable named `Label`. Give it some other name.